# is it not possible to open an encrypted sqlite3 db file with knex?

Tags: node.js, sqlite, electron, knex.js, sqlcipher

I'm trying to open `Sqlcipher` database file with `Knex` in electron, but using sqlite3 client in `Knex` wont accept it,
is what i'm trying to do even possible or should i use another library.

Here's what i have tried :

1_ created `sqlcipher` db file with DB Browser for SQLCipher and encrypted it using tools -> set encryption.

2_ here's me trying to open and query the db in electron

```
const myDBConfig = { 

client: "sqlite3",
connection: {
 filename: __dirname.concat("/../../enc_schema.db")
 },
 pool: {
    afterCreate: function(conn, done) {
        conn.run("PRAGMA KEY = 'secret'");
        done();
    }  
 } 
}
const knex = require('knex')(myDBConfig);
```

the output is : SQLITE_NOTADB: file is not a database.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and include what you have tried, as well as any error messages you're getting ("it won't accept it" is not very helpful) so that we can actually help you. Thanks!

Comment: @AlexanderLeithner ok, i did.

Comment: Looks like sqlite driver cannot read that ciphered DB.